# Atomic searching and creating entities on demand with SQL/Doctrine2

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I want to associate bookmarks with tags. Tags may not exist yet.

```
-- see source after questions for complete schema
Bookmark:     _id_|…
Tag:          _id_|_title_|…
bookmark_tag: _bookmark_id|_tag_id_
```

Current solution:

```
if tag exists : load tag (id) from db
else          : store tag to db // non-atomic operation => duplicates possible

link tag with bookmark
```

For every tag the database is requested to search for it and return the location (`id`). I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.

More important is the **non-atomic** operation done, when storing a new bookmark. Tags have a unique `title`, so storing a duplicate will result in an Exception (`PDOException`), which will close Doctrine's `EntitiyManager`.

While searching for the tag and storing it, another process could create the tag, so the first process will break while creating a duplicated entity.

I am using Symfony2 with Doctrine2. DB-Backend is MySQL, but i hope for a generic (Doctrine2) solution.

**Questions**

How would you solve this dilemma? Do you know a better solution?

Is Doctrine2 able to create missing Tags on demand and use existings ones when `addTag(Tag $tag)`-ing them to `Bookmark`?

---

**Source/BookmarkController.php**

```
/**
 * Creates a new Bookmark entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="bookmarks_create")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("XBookmarksBundle:Bookmark:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new Bookmark();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new BookmarkType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        // static tag for testing
        $tagTitle = 'Lorem Ipsum';

        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XBookmarksBundle:Tag')
            ->findBy(array('title' => $tagTitle));

        // found tag => use it
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            $tag = $result[0];
        }

        // create new tag
        else {
            // FATAL not atomic => tag could exists now

            $tag = new Tag();
            $tag->setTitle($tagTitle);
        }

        // add tag to bookmark
        $entity->addTag($tag);

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bookmarks_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }
```

**Source/Bookmark.php**

```
/**
 * X\BookmarksBundle\Entity\Bookmark
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="X\BookmarksBundle\Entity\BookmarkRepository")
 */
class Bookmark
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string $uri
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uri", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $uri;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var datetime $deleted_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $deleted_at;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) */
    private $tags;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getTags () {
            return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag (Tag $tag) {
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    public function setTags ($tags) {
        // TODO
    }

    /* DEFAULT SETTERS AND GETTERS FOR OTHER ATTRIBUTES */
}
```

**Source/Tag.php**

```
/**
 * X\BookmarksBundle\Entity\Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="X\BookmarksBundle\Entity\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     * -- ORM\Id
     * -- ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var datetime $deleted_at
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleted_at;


    public function __construct () {
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime('now');
        $this->id=42;
        $this->title="le fu";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
// ...
// create new tag
else {
    try {
        $tag = new Tag();
        $tag->setTitle($tagTitle);
        $em->persist($tag);
        $em->flush();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // also you could check for exception code here
        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XBookmarksBundle:Tag')
            ->findBy(array('title' => $tagTitle));

        // found tag
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            $tag = $result[0];
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
        }

    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea. The problem with your solution is, that it is neither atomic, simple (n tags => up to 3*n database query's) nor reliable (if deleting tags would be possible => "Something went wrong").